# angularjs cros get json ,parse error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I try to use angularjs $http.get to get json.
My Server has cros and in fact ,if I just open the url in browser, it's correct .
I use firefox, this is my screenshot:
[image]

the error:
[image]

you see the first OPTIONS succeeds.
Here is my js code

```
var single=angular.module('searchSingle', []);

single.controller('name',  function($scope,$http){

var url='http://115.159.97.98/php/stocks.php';
estimate=function (){
    $http.get(url).success(function (data,status){
        alert("aa");
    }).error(function(){
    });
}

$scope.$watch('searchHelper', estimate);
});
```

The result is it jumps to the error function, and as you see in the screenshot, it trans only 0KB and the real response is 200+KB.
Another thing is if I use $http.jsonp, it can trans 200+KB but also jumps to the error function 
and the server code is:
[image]

Comment: I guess it is a small bug because everything seems correct. orz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if you use CROS, the server response must have headers:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

add the headers on your server response

but I don't know why